# Before insert MariaDB trigger don´t works

Tags: sql, triggers, insert, mariadb

I need to fill the cod_unico column with the created(TIMESTAMP) and id(AUTOINCREMENT) data, i can not do it with php because the other two columns are generated in MariaDB and obiusly don´t wanna change that, so i tried a after insert trigger update but i get this error Error: Can't update table 'usuarios' in stored function/trigger because it is 
already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

i tried this code in a before insert trigger

```
    DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `agregar_cod_unico`;
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `agregar_cod_unico` BEFORE INSERT ON `usuarios` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
    SET new.cod_unico = CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(new.created, '%y'),DATE_FORMAT(new.created, '%m'),SUBSTR(UPPER(md5(new.id)),10,4));
    END
```

It don't give me any error but is not working, the id_unico column still null after an insertion but, if i replace the new.created with some static string and also for the new.id, it works, i think maybe this values are generated after the insertion? anyway how can i get the value for cod_unico and insert it in each insertion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i solve it, i can not use the created and id columns because is an before insert, but instead i could use now() for the TIMESTAMP and a little select to get the autoincremented id, so the functional code is:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `agregar_cod_alumno`;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `agregar_cod_alumno` BEFORE INSERT ON `usuarios` 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 

DECLARE user_id int default 0; 
SELECT auto_increment into user_id 
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_name = 'usuarios' 
AND table_schema = database(); 

SET new.cod_alumno = CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(now(), '%y'),DATE_FORMAT(now(), '%m'),SUBSTR(UPPER(md5(user_id)),10,4)); 

END
```